# TestContext is null when invoking method using Reflection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, mstest, .net-4.8

I am invoking a Data Driven Test Method from another service using Reflection. This Data Driven test read the data from file using TestContext and it is null. The purpose of this service is to run all the End to End tests available in the UnitTest1 class.

When I am running the same test using Test Explorer, it works fine.

Below is the code block for the Unit Test Class:

```
[TestClass]
class UnitTest1
{
   public TestContext TestContext {get; set;}

   [TestMethod] 
   [DeploymentItem("Data.xml")]       
   [DataSource(
            "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML",
            "Data.xml",
            "DataParameters",
            DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]               
   [Timeout(60000)]        
   public void TestMethod1()
   {
     string field1 = this.TestContext.DataRow["Field1"].ToString();
     string field2 = this.TestContext.DataRow["Field2"].ToString();
   }

   [TestMethod]
   [DeploymentItem("Data.xml")]
   [Timeout(60000)]
   public void VerifyDataFile()
   {
            string file = "Data.xml";
            Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(file), "deployment failed: " + file + " did not get deployed");
   }
}
```

The csproj of the Unit Test Project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <-- Some dependencies -->

  <ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="..\..\..\folder\Data.xml" Link="Data.xml">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     </Content>
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Now the Project class code from where this Unit test is getting called:

```
public class ExecuteTests
{
        private UnitTest1 unitTestObj;

        public ExecuteTests()
        {
            this.unitTestObj = UnitTest1();
        }

        public void RunAll()
        {
           MethodInfo[] methods = unitTestObj.GetType().GetMethods();
           
           foreach (MethodInfo? method in methods)
            {
                var task = method.Invoke(unitTestObj, new object?[0]);
            }
        }
}
```

It gives the following error:

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

while debugging I got to know TestContext is null when test method is getting called using reflection. Is there any way to set the expected TestContext so the reflection code does not fail?
I also tried to set the TestContext in the ExecuteTests class like below but it's still null.

```
private TestContext testContextInstance;
public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get { return this.testContextInstance; }
            set { this.testContextInstance = value; }
        }

public void RunAll()
        {
           MethodInfo[] methods = unitTestObj.GetType().GetMethods();
           
           foreach (MethodInfo? method in methods)
            {
                if (method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), true).Length > 0)
                {
                    unitTestObj.TestContext = this.testContextInstance;
                }

                var task = method.Invoke(unitTestObj, new object?[0]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your reflection code is trying to act like the test host/runner, it will need to *act like the test host/runner*. It sounds like one of the things the test host/runner does normally is: set any members of type `TestContext` to an instance of a test context; that means *your code would have to do that instead*; it looks like `TestContext` is `abstract` with a `protected` constructor, so you'd also need to implement your own `MyTestContext : TestContext` type; check the test instance for instance members of type `TestContext` and if you find any: instantiate and configure your context object, and assign to those members.

Or perhaps simpler: just use the default test host/runner. It'll be a lot easier than trying to emulate all the features and behaviors of a complex test tool. For example, right now you're also failing to:

- restrict the executed methods to *instance* methods marked with suitable attributes such as `[TestMethod]`
- support `[DeploymentItem(...)]`
- support `[Timeout(...)]`
- support `[DataSource(...)]`
- run past failing tests, reporting tests and failures at the end
- (and that's just the features you're *actually using*)

You might also want to think about things like "async" (how to handle `Task[<T>]`/`ValueTask[<T>]` return types), whether you need to worry about sync-context, shared state / "fixtures", parallelization, capturing per-test STDOUT data, test-framework-specific logging (the equivalent of `ITestOutputHelper` from XUnit - although I note that `TestContext` has `WriteLine` methods which may achieve this), cancellation (the `TestContext.CancellationTokenSource`), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean by default test host/runner? I understood that just invoking unit test method by reflection, wouldn't provide any feature. It makes me wonder if there is any other way to trigger All Unit tests or required unit tests in production.

Comment: I mean: normally you run these tests via `dotnet test` or via some UI runner, which in turn invokes the test runner which *does all the things you're talking about*; if you want to automate the test runner, you'll need to investigate the automation API for that specific runner, but: that isn't a reflection thing. If you want to use reflection, then *you are pretending to be the test runner*, and *you'll* have to do all the things

Comment: Got it. I need to investigate a way to run data driven test from my project. This project has some Rest APIs which run the asked test or all tests in the Production environment hence was using reflection.